# the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'-django for user validation

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three different fileds username,password and role if all these three values matches then user will be able to login else he will not be able to login.

```
import json
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import serializers


def loginemployee(request):
      body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
      body = json.loads(body_unicode)
      payload = body['username']
      passwordcheck = body['password']
      rolecheck = body['role']
      if payload:
          employee=models.Employees.objects.filter(Q(username=payload['username']) & Q(password=passwordcheck['password']) & (Q(role=rolecheck['role']) | Q(backup_role=payload['role'])))
          # employees1=models.Employees.objects.filter(Q(email=payload['username']) & Q(role=payload['role']))
          # empl=(employee+employees1);
          if employee:
              emp = serializers.serialize('json', employee)
              return HttpResponse(emp,content_type='application/json')
```

can you help me the fix the issue in the above code.
i am getting error message string indices must be integers

Comment: Please provide the whole error output.

Comment: string indices must be integers but i am not sure that the code is perfect the idea is to get the values as json and validate.

Comment: `employee=models.Employees.objects.filter` this isn't ONE employee. Filter returns a queryset (list of objects). So the var should be `employees`. I don't know enough about the serialiser. But if you expect to give it a single object, then you are mistaken.